# PageFactory gives null pointer exception

Tags: java, appium

I am trying to create a test framework using POM, but whenever I use `PageFactory` it gives a `NullPointerException`.

I am simply trying to open the app and check where given elements are present on page or not.

Here is my Driver class:

```
public class Driver extends BaseSetup
{ 
    protected AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    public Driver() {
        this.driver = super.getDriver();
    }
}
```

Here is my BaseSetup class:

```
public class BaseSetup {

    private DesiredCapabilities capabilities;// = new DesiredCapabilities();
    protected AndroidDriver<MobileElement> androidDriver = null;

    private String appiumPort="4723";
    private String serverIp="0.0.0.0";

  //String workingDevice = "emulator-5554";
    String workingDevice = "d6f08719";

    @BeforeClass                                                                                                                            
    public void setup() {
        initDriver();
    }


    public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> getDriver() {
        return androidDriver;
    }

    private void initDriver() {
        System.out.println("Inside initDriver method");

      //  DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "OnePlus6T");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", workingDevice);
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.ServiceApp.Vivek");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".MainActivity");
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");
        String serverUrl = "http://" + serverIp + ":" + appiumPort + "/wd/hub";


        try
        {
            System.out.println("Argument to driver object : " + serverUrl);
            androidDriver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(serverUrl), capabilities);

        }
        catch (NullPointerException | MalformedURLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("appium driver could not be initialised for device ");
        }
        System.out.println("Driver in initdriver is : "+androidDriver);

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        androidDriver.quit();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(Method method) {
        System.out.println("Starting Method :" + method.getName());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod(Method method) {
        System.out.println("Ending Method :" + method.getName());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    }

}
```

Here is my OpenApplication class:

```
public class OpenApplication extends Driver{

    public OpenApplication(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        super();
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), OpenApplication.class);
    }

    public void validatePageLoaded() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("timer start");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("timer end");
        String str=newUser.getText();
        System.out.println(str);

        System.out.println("Successfully");
        if (newUser.isDisplayed() && existingCustomer.isDisplayed()
                && welcomeText.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("App open Successfully..!");

        } else {
            System.out.println("App is not loaded..!");
        }
    }


        @CacheLookup
        @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.view.View[@index='2']")
        public WebElement newUser;

        @CacheLookup
        @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.view.View[@index='4']")
        public WebElement existingCustomer;

        @CacheLookup
        @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.view.View[@text='Welcome To Bajaj Finserv']")
        public WebElement welcomeText;



}
```

Here is my OpenApplicationTest class:

```
public class OpenApplicationTest extends Driver {

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void openApplicationValidation() throws InterruptedException {
        OpenApplication openApplication= new OpenApplication(driver);           
        openApplication.validatePageLoaded();       
    }
}
```

I am getting Below Error:

```
FAILED: openApplicationValidation
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.datamato.pages.OpenApplication.validatePageLoaded(OpenApplication.java:34)
    at com.datamato.tests.OpenApplicationTest.openApplicationValidation(OpenApplicationTest.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1130)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
```

What should I do to correct it?

Comment: Can you highlight which line in the function is crashing ? Its not clear what's at Line No 34

Comment: @ShreyTrivedi thanks for your quick response, below line is crashing in **function:String str=newUser.getText();**

Comment: @Vivek, I am still not getting which line is crashing ? Can you please show it here ?

Comment: @ShreyTrivedi Please look into **class OpenApplication -> method validatePageLoaded() in that fouth line String str=newUser.getText();**

Comment: ok..at which stage is 'WebElement newUser' expected to get initialized ?

Comment: @ShreyTrivedi after opening my application, I am trying to see 'WebElement newUser' is enabled or not ?

Comment: @Vivek Conceptually is OpenApplication suppose to use the same driver that OpenApplicationTest passes to it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193808/discussion-between-shrey-trivedi-and-vivek).

Answer (score 0):

Following is the flow of your program

1. OpenApplication class object calls parametrized constructor i.e. 
     `OpenApplication(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) { }`
2. Then `super();` calls Driver class constructor

   `public Driver() {this.driver = super.getDriver();}`
3. Then `super.getDriver();` method calls BaseSetup class `getDriver` method which returns  `androidDriver`;

What I am almost sure is `@BeforeClass` annotation method is never called so `androidDriver` is not initialized.

```
// System.out.println("Driver in initdriver is : "+androidDriver); This must have not printed.
```

This may not be a good solution but you can try following like put `initDriver` method in `getDriver`   so that driver can be initialized before it is used.

**Solution:**

```
public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> getDriver() {
initDriver();
return androidDriver;
}
```

Comment: Hey Amit, Thank you for your quick response, but my @BeforeClass annotation method is calling androidDriver, please look below console output for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

@Amit Jain, Thank you for your quick response, as you mention that my @BeforeClass method not calling androidDriver, but its calling and printing also statement. please find below console output for your reference.

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\DL41\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--572591171\testng-customsuite.xml

Inside initDriver method
Argument to driver object : http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub
May 23, 2019 10:03:30 AM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Driver in initdriver is : io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver, Capabilities: {appActivity=.MainActivity, appPackage=com.BajajServiceApp.VikramUAT, databaseEnabled=false, desired={platformName=android, appActivity=.MainActivity, appPackage=com.BajajServiceApp.VikramUAT, deviceName=OnePlus6T, noReset=true, udid=d6f08719}, deviceManufacturer=OnePlus, deviceModel=ONEPLUS A6010, deviceName=d6f08719, deviceScreenSize=1080x2340, deviceUDID=d6f08719, javascriptEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=true, noReset=true, platform=LINUX, platformName=Android, platformVersion=9, takesScreenshot=true, udid=d6f08719, warnings={}, webStorageEnabled=false}
Starting Method :openApplicationValidation
-----------------------------------------
timer start
timer end
Ending Method :openApplicationValidation
-----------------------------------------
FAILED: openApplicationValidation
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.datamato.pages.OpenApplication.validatePageLoaded(OpenApplication.java:34)
    at com.datamato.tests.OpenApplicationTest.openApplicationValidation(OpenApplicationTest.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1130)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
```